# How to disable text shaking when I click a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, widget

I am working with buttons in Tkinter, Python.

The thing is when I click in one button the text of the button shakes. It might be a default behavior for this widget and I don't know how to disable it and make it static.

Comment: Can you give a minimal code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you mean the relief change from raised to sunken when you click a button.

This is what I found on http://wiki.tcl.tk/1048 (click 'Show Discussion' to see it):

> Unfortunately, the relief used when you click is hardcoded (as
>   'sunken'), so you can't configure it per-widget without hacking the Tk
>   internals for the  binding for buttons.

So the simplest way around this would be to always make the button appear sunken

```
MyButton = Tkinter.Button(
    self.frame, 
    text = "Foobar", 
    command = self.foobar, 
    relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN
)
```

The disadvantage of that is that it might make the button look unresponsive.

You can also use a widget other than a button to be used as a clickable item (suggested by Joel Cornett). Here is a simple example with a label used as a button:

```
import Tkinter

class main:
        def __init__(self,root):
                # make a label with some space around the text
                self.lbl1 = Tkinter.Label(root,
                                          width = 16, height = 4,
                                          text = "Foobar")                
                self.lbl1.pack()

                # Call a function when lbl1 is clicked
                # <Button-1> means a left mouse button click
                self.lbl1.bind("<Button-1>", self.yadda)
                self.lbl1.bind("<Enter>", self.green)
                self.lbl1.bind("<Leave>", self.red)

        def yadda(self, event):
                self.lbl1.config(text="Clicked!")

        def green(self, event):
                self.lbl1.config(bg="green")

        def red(self,event):
                self.lbl1.config(bg="red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One could also use a canvas object instead of a button. It would not be that difficult to DIY a click/hover animation.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you Junuxx.
Isn't there a way to solve this rather than make the button always appear sunken?

Comment: Yes, you can use a canvas, like Joel suggested. Or a Label if just text is enough. I'll include an example in my answer.

Comment: I see. That's another good alternative, not too good as the last one becouse if I do that, I wouldn't miss important options like ACTIVEBACKGROUND, ACTIVEFOREGROUND and so on...

Do you know how to hack Tk internals to make all buttons relief to FLAT? I wouldn't bother becouse the behavior of the button when you press it (I mean, the change from whatever you want-FLAT,RAISED, etc- to SUNKEN is just ugly.

Comment: I don't see the problem, you could just change the label's foreground and background when required, right? You could also bind the enter and leave events to make the label change when the mouse is over it, for example. As for hacking it in Tk, no, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it as a reference, I took @Junuxx code and modified it to create what I consider a drop-in replacement for a Ttk Button. I reconfigured some options to make it behave as closely as possible to a Ttk Button:

```py
from tkinter import Event
from tkinter.ttk import Widget, Label

class FlatButton(Label):
    '''This label behaves like a button, without click animation

    By default the label has no borders

    It can be used like a button, with the same initial values. Please consider
    however that this is still a label for styling.

    Took inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674950/3368201

    Options comparison:

    - Some options are common to both and behave the same: class, compound,
        cursor, image, style, text, textvariable, underline, width
    - Some are common to both, but behave differently:
        - takefocus -> it has a different default value; managed in __init__
                       (point #2)
    - Some are only present in BUTTON:
        - command -> it is managed in a more "pythonic" way using a global
                     wrapper and special cases in bind, unbind and configure.
                     It is also managed in __init__ (point #1)
    - Some are only present in LABEL; these values can be redefined in the
        __init__ call or through configure,: anchor (default value changed to
        'center'), background, font, foreground, justify, padding, relief,
        wraplength, borderwidth
    '''

    @staticmethod
    def overriden_default_states() -> dict[str, Any]:
        '''Provide default states for properties

        These values will be set when not passed in __init__

        Returns:
            dict[str, Any]: The dictionary with the properties and their value
        '''
        return {
                'takefocus': True,
                'anchor': 'center'
            }

    def __init__(self, parent: Widget = None, **kw):
        '''Construct a Ttk Button-like widget with the provided parent.

        This is in fact a Label, with some button behavior implemented inside.

        See class description for more info on what is allowed

        Args:
            parent (Widget, optional): The parent widget. Defaults to None.
        '''
        # 1) Manually manage command
        self._command = kw.pop('command', None)

        # 2) If not provided, set overriden_default_states
        for k, v in self.overriden_default_states().items():
            if k not in kw:
                kw[k] = v

        # Create the button
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)

        # All events in _click_binds will trigger a command
        self._click_binds = {'<Button-1>': [], '<space>': []}

        # Bind them to the special wrapper function
        for seq in self._click_binds.keys():
            super().bind(seq, lambda ev, seq=seq: self.click_event(seq, ev))

    # ------------------------
    # Command management

    def click_event(self, sequence: str, event: Event):
        '''The _btn_pressed_sequence was triggered

        Args:
            event (Event): The event data
        '''
        for b in self._click_binds.get(sequence, []):
            b(event)

        self.invoke()

    def invoke(self) -> Any:
        '''If there is a command, call it

        If the button is disabled nothing will be done

        Returns:
            Any: The command return value if it is executed, otherwise None
        '''
        if self._command and not self.instate(['disabled']):
            return self._command()

    def bind(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None):
        '''Overriding bind to extract the _btn_pressed_sequence
        '''
        if sequence in self._click_binds.keys():
            if (not func) or (not add):
                self._click_binds[sequence].clear()
            if func:
                self._click_binds[sequence].append(func)
            result = '__unsupported__'
        else:
            result = super().bind(sequence, func, add)

        return result

    def unbind(self, sequence, funcid=None):
        '''Overriding unbind to extract the _btn_pressed_sequence
        '''
        if sequence in self._click_binds.keys():
            self._click_binds[sequence].clear()
        else:
            super().unbind(sequence, funcid)

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kw):
        '''Overriding unbind to extract the command
        '''
        if 'command' in kw:
            self._command = kw.pop('command', None)
        return self.configure(cnf, kw)
```

The default appearence is a flat button, but you can change it to `relief='raised'` in the constructor, then use it as a common button:

```py
def command(self):
    print("Clicked command!")

def yadda(self, event):
    print("Clicked yadda!")

btn = FlatButton(root, text='aaa', relief='raised', command=command)
btn.pack()
btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.yadda)
```

Then the object will manage correctly the command and the bind, in both enabled and disabled states, and will not move when clicked

Differences with "real" button:

- There is no "focus" highlight
- It has some additional features (e.g. the `anchor` and `foreground` properties)
- In the style, it shall inherit from the `TLable`