# Make Button in Python Tkinter Stop Moving when Pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

So I am working on making an application inside of Tkinter and I am not that experienced in it, but I noticed that when you press a button it moves the text inside down and to the right just a couple pixels and I can't figure out how to make it not do that. Any help finding what parameter I need to change would be greatly appreciated.

I tried finding any docs on the subject but whenever I looked it up I would only get things that pertained to how to place a button on the window or in a frame/canvas with place, grid, pack.

Comment: That's not something you're going to be able to change.  However, you could display the text using a Label instead, and use `.bind()` to make it respond to mouse clicks.  By playing with the widget options such as `relief`, you could make the Label look and behave quite like a Button, while still leaving out the text-shifting feature.

Answer (score 1):

will you can change the relief value to be SUNKEN and adjust the border values like this

`Button(root, text = 'Click me !', borderwidth=5, relief=SUNKEN)`
the button will look a little weird
or you can use widget other than a button just like this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674950/20411925)

```
import tkinter

class main:
        def __init__(self,root):
                # make a label with some space around the text
                self.lbl1 = tkinter.Label(root,
                                          width = 16, height = 4,
                                          text = "Foobar")                
                self.lbl1.pack()

                # Call a function when lbl1 is clicked
                # <Button-1> means a left mouse button click
                self.lbl1.bind("<Button-1>", self.yadda)
                self.lbl1.bind("<Enter>", self.green)
                self.lbl1.bind("<Leave>", self.red)

        def yadda(self, event):
                self.lbl1.config(text="Clicked!")

        def green(self, event):
                self.lbl1.config(bg="green")

        def red(self,event):
                self.lbl1.config(bg="red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```